# Difference between support-v4.app.fragment and app.fragment?

Tags: android

I am new to fragments and had a question:
When I updated my SDK tool and went to create a project(min = api8, the default one), I noticed the android-support-v4.jar in my Referenced Library.

When I extended my class and tried to use the `Fragment` class, I found out there are 2. One is android.app.Fragment and other is android.support.v4.app.Fragment. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're developing for Android 3+, you can use app.Fragment.

However, in 3-, Fragments didn't exist yet. That is where the support library comes in. It provides Fragments for older versions of Android.

See also [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Comment: what happen if I am developing app for both 3+ and 3-?

Comment: You can use the Fragment from the support library. When run on a 3+ device, it uses the normal Fragment automatically, else it continues using the library.

Comment: @NiekHaarman , just looked at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) on dev.android and supposedly, it does not switch the framework to the normal fragments when running on 3+. It just continues using the support implementation.