# Fragment and Activity Issues

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to create a simple set of screens in an android app. The app begins with a menu screen with buttons. After a choice is made I then want to launch an activity built with 2 fragments (one for player 1 and another for player 2). However when I try and start the activity with the fragments I get an error in the android emulator.

Here is my code so far:

The main menu code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// load up 1v1 duel activity
public void beginRegularDuel(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneVsOneDuelActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

The 1v1 Duel Code:

```
package com.PigRam.magichelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class OneVsOneDuelActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.one_vs_one_view);
}
}
```

The Player One fragment code:

```
package com.PigRam.magichelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class PlayerOneDuelFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_vs_one_view, container, false);
}
}
```

And Player Two:

```
package com.PigRam.magichelper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PlayerTwoDuelFragment extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_vs_one_view, container, false);
}
}
```

And layout for main menu

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/main_menu_title"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/regular_duel"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/regular_duel"
        android:onClick="beginRegularDuel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two_headed_dragon"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/two_headed_dragon" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Duel Screen layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:baselineAligned="false">

<fragment android:name="com.PigRam.magichelper.PlayerOneDuelFragment"
    android:id="@+id/player_one_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<fragment android:name="com.PigRam.magichelper.PlayerTwoDuelFragment"
    android:id="@+id/player_two_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.PigRam.magichelper"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.PigRam.magichelper.MainMenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.PigRam.magichelper.OneVsOneDuelActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

And last but not least here is the error log:

```
05-09 09:40:18.696: D/gralloc_goldfish(1521): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-09 09:40:22.746: D/AndroidRuntime(1521): Shutting down VM
05-09 09:40:22.756: W/dalvikvm(1521): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-09 09:40:22.916: D/dalvikvm(1521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 191K, 11% free 2634K/2956K, paused 75ms+122ms, total 303ms
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.PigRam.magichelper/com.PigRam.magichelper.OneVsOneDuelActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at com.PigRam.magichelper.OneVsOneDuelActivity.onCreate(OneVsOneDuelActivity.java:13)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     ... 11 more
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.PigRam.magichelper.PlayerOneDuelFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
05-09 09:40:22.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1521):     ... 21 more
```

Sorry for all the code but this is really bugging me. I am new to Android programming so please help me out!

Thanks.

Comment: you should post the error also (logcat)

Comment: Firstly, what Android OS is your emulator? This code will only work on 3.0+. Also, can't really help you without the Fragment code. I've often found you need the right constructors for this code to work.

Comment: It is emulating a Google Nexus 7 tablet. I'm at work right now so ill post the logcat error messages when I get home.

Comment: @Ali ahh sorry, i thought i included the fragment code, i missed that, will post that up tonight

Comment: @Nunu log cat is there now

Comment: @Ali fragment code is there now as well as logcat, I think it may be something wrong with the fragment inflation but I have no idea why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Fragments` are using the `one_vs_one_view` layout which is the same as your `Activity`. You cannot do this, the fragment can't keep expanding itself indefinitely.

This is your only issue. I've tried to run your code by giving your fragments a different layout (one that only contains a `TextView` inside a `RelativeLayout`) and everything works fine.

I tried it in a 4.2.2 phone and a 2.1 phone.

Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class OneVsOneDuelActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.one_vs_one_view);
    }
}
```

Fragment 1:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PlayerOneDuelFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_world, container, false);
    }
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PlayerTwoDuelFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.hellow_world, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: so basically i need a layout file for each fragment file (or use the same layout for both fragments since they will have the same structure), plus a layout for my FragmentActivity, and another for my Main Activity, so that would make 4 or 5 layouts total (depending on if I define a different layout for each fragment or use one for both?)

Comment: The `Fragment`s need a layout, they can have the same layout or different layouts that's your choice. If you do use the same layout then dont do `getActivity().findViewById()` since more than 1 element with the same id will exist. Instead in each fragment do `getView().findViewById()`. Yes, your `MainActivity` will have whatever layout you want it to have. I would make a Fragment for that as well just incase you need to restructure it later or change the layout for a tablet or something. Please accept the answer if it's correct.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it out yet since I'm at work. But I'm almost 100% certain that you are correct. You will be getting a +1 and tick by tonight most likely

Comment: Your solution was correct as i suspected. Cheers for the help Ali and @Nunu (who really tried to help me), I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment classes you should import

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

instead of

```
android.app.Fragment;
```

that's why it's telling you `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.PigRam.magichelper.PlayerOneDuelFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

And your activity should extend `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: what is the difference between the two?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769423/difference-between-support-v4-app-fragment-and-app-fragment

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same issue as before

Comment: did you modify it in both your fragments?

Comment: I sure did, ill updated the code posted here to reflect the changes

Comment: also your activity should extend android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Comment: I have that code already except for FragmentManager, but when I import that Eclipse tells me I do not need it.

Comment: if you are not using it, then do not import it..the error is still the same??

Comment: yep unfortunately its still complaining about an inflate exception. Could this have anything to do with my MainActivity not liking the call to a FragmentActivity?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29659/discussion-between-nunu-and-matthew-pigram)